# sbt shows info messages as error in fork mode

Tags: scala, sbt, slf4j

Trying to use sbt with

Keys.fork := true

With this option all messages from slf4j logger shown as error-message

It looks like

```
[error] 0 [main] INFO test - Test
```

Without fork it looks like

```
1 [run-main] INFO test - Test
```

- sbt version: 0.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking.html , in the “Configuring output” section:

> By default, forked output is sent to the Logger, with standard output logged at the Info level and standard error at the Error level. This can be configured with the outputStrategy setting,